# How to change thickness/width of arrow head?

Tags: libreoffice

When drawing an arrow in LibreOffice DRAW (or IMPRESS) I can change the width of the line, but not the arrowhead itself. How can I change the width of the arrow head?

Answer (score 19):

While writing this, I found a solution: 
http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=8674

1. Right-click on the arrow -> "Line ..."
2. now you can change the size of the arrow's head: 
   [image: edit width of arrowhead]

Comment: Stupid question maybe. How did you draw that green arrow in your picture?

Comment: I did it with Shutter: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/

Comment: Do you know how to save this change?

Comment: I find this changes every arrow in the diagram.  How can I change the arrowhead on just one line?

Comment: Found an alternative "solution": in my version, there seems to be no such setting (has it been removed?). My initial problem, perhaps similarly to the OP's, was that default arrowheads are too big if you use them the default A4 page size. So what I ended up doing is just using a bigger sized page to start with (see this https://libreofficehelp.com/change-page-size-libreoffice-draw/), then, on a bigger canvas, like on A1, default sizes of arrows (unchangeable, in my case) make much more sense.

Comment: This is such a lifesaver!